# Two submit buttons (with different action) for the same form

Tags: javascript, html

I have a html form which requires two submit buttons.  Each button when clicked needs to catch the event (form submission) then process form data and move forward or backward in GUI depending in which one of the two buttons was pressed.

I haven't found a way to catch in Javascript which button was pressed in submit event handler.  When using click event handler no form is attached to this action.  Any advice?

Answer (score 0):

Instead of `click` event, I prefer using `submit` event of forms, which includes a `submitter` property indicating which button was clicked. (Bonus: form get validated before `submit` fired).

```js
form.addEventListener('submit', (event) => {
  if (event.submitter.name === 'action-a') doActionA();
  else if (event.submitter.name === 'action-b') doACtionB();
});
```

Edit: It turned out that `SubmitEvent.submiter` is a relatively new feature which may not work for some browsers[1]. I switched to the following approach:

```js
let submitter = '';
buttons.forEach((btn) => btn.addEventListener('click', () => submitter = btn.name));
form.addEventListener('submit', (event) => {
  if (submitter === 'action-a') doActionA();
  else if (submitter === 'action-b') doACtionB();
});
```

[1] https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/SubmitEvent/submitter#browser_compatibility

Answer (score -1):

The event object has a property on it called `target` which is a reference to the DOM node that triggered the event. It should contain the button that was clicked.

Comment: Yes, but `event.target` brings all the form objects like inputs and the two buttons, I haven't found a way of catching which button triggered the event.

Comment: Could you bind to the click event on the button instead of listening for the submit event on the form?

Comment: If I do, the click event don't bring the form, just bring the button as event.  I need the form to process the data.

Answer (score -1):

Use 2 different names for the 2 buttons and capture the click event. The name would let you identify and work upon the specified button pressed.

Comment: When I capture the click, the event attached brings only the button clicked and not all the form with their inputs.  I need the form to process it.

Comment: You can pass the form object during the button click. You can call a Javascript function and pass the form object.

Comment: Something similar to this..                                                               <html> <form action="demo_form.asp" method="get">
  First name: <input type="text" name="fname"><br>
  Last name: <input type="text" name="lname"><br>
  <button type="submit">Submit</button>
  <button type="submit" formmethod="post" formaction="demo_post.asp">Submit using POST</button>
</form> </html>

Comment: Actually I'm using javascript and not ASP.    If you can please show in your example how to catch: 1. The form data   2. The button clicked.

Answer (score -1):

As shown in https://jsfiddle.net/0fuq5dhf/1/:

```
var form = document.getElementById("frmData");
form.addEventListener("click", function(event) {
    var formData = $( '#' + event.currentTarget.id ).serialize();
  if(event.target.id == "submit1") {
    //Process for first submit button
    console.log(formData);
  } else {
    //process for the 2nd submit button
    console.log(formData);
  }

});
```

you can get the target to determine which button is clicked and serialize the form data to process based on button clicked.

Comment: Could you show how the data is to be serialised in code? At the moment it's logging to the console rather than serialising.

Comment: @Deiva, `event.target.id` actually returns the form id and not the button id.

Comment: it depends on how / for which event you are attaching the handler. If you see the fiddle url, i am attaching the click event for the form. The other way could be attaching the event for the button itself.

Comment: Thanks @Deiva, It actually works, but not in a efficient way probably since the click function runs each time any area of the form is clicked (like inputs).